# how to show Run time error message or sql error message in the same jsp in spring mvc 3.0

Tags: spring-mvc

```
When any exception occured in catch block then how can we show the error message in the same jsp i.e employee.jsp and how to jsp should look like?
am getting this error message in the console;what is the meaning of this error?
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.kesava.tutorial.controller.HomeController.addEmployee(com.kesava.tutorial.dto.EmployeeDTO,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws com.kesava.tutorial.util.SpringUtilException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable resolver for argument [0] [type=com.kesava.tutorial.dto.EmployeeDTO]
@RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ExceptionHandler({ SpringUtilException.class })
    public ModelAndView addEmployee(@Valid EmployeeDTO employeeDTO,
            BindingResult result) throws SpringUtilException {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("employee");
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            List employees = employeeDao.getAllEmployees();
            return new ModelAndView("employee", "employeeList", employees);
        } else {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(employeeDTO, employees);
            System.out.println("addEmployee employees! " + employees);
            try {
                employeeDao.persist(employees);
            } catch (EntityExistsException e) {
                throw new SpringUtilException(e, "Employee Duplicate");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new SpringUtilException(ex, "Failed to add Employee");
            }
            // after inserting show the employees
            List employees1 = employeeDao.getAllEmployees();


            mav.addObject("isDataSaved" , "Data saved Successfully");
            mav.addObject("employeeList" , employees1);

            return mav;

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the error within the JSP output, do not use  System.out.println. Instead, add the exception stack trace to a model object you print out in your JSP.

Something like:

```
try { 
   employeeDao.persist(employees); 
} 
catch (EntityExistsException e) { 
   model.addAttribute("error", e.getMessage()); 
}
```

That way you can see the exception in the JSP, and print it. You can access it by the attribute key, like this:
`${error}`

Comment: i put like this in catch block catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("at line 104");
    mav.addObject("isDataSaved" , ex.getMessage());
    throw new SpringUtilException(ex, "Failed to add Employee");
   }                                                          but am getting below exception                                                            at line 104
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler

Comment: added some more detail to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug the code. What the error means spring could not invoke the method in the controller it is failing due to binding.

1.Just read it carefully it says illegal state exception which cannot be handled by the exception handler since you are handling only SpringUtilException

2.And secondly There is not a suitable resolver for the  argument check your httprequest and verify all the parameters are passed correctly the mapping failure usually in most cases will be date format mismatch or the data type mismatch